# f series ip cam: ptz get request from arduino

Tags: arduino, get, ip-camera

I have a IP camera in homenetwork. I can control it by web access. I want to send a request from arduino program (in the same homenetwork) that will control ptz of camera. How can I find  the link - part of script ... to turn camera on preset position? Arduino + ethernet schield is controled from web server out of my homenetwork and I want to use it to control ptz of camera.

Comment: what security has the camera? https? login and password authentication?

Comment: It is HTTP with login and password. Is possible to set "visitor" account, too.

Comment: can you add to question the http request you want to make from Arduino? use F12 tool of the browser to get the request line, request headers and request body. Body only if it is a POST request.

Comment: I have poor experiences with this, can you explain me how to get request line ...

Comment: pozerám, si zo Slovenska, kde ťa môžem kontaktovať v slovenčine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184592/discussion-between-juraj-and-kamera-prva).